# Decode GPS Data - No idea what the format is

Tags: parsing, gps, format, tracking

I have a GPS tracker that a friend lent me. It's a chinese model, with sparse documentation.
It's got a built in gps and a gprs module (sim) and it's sending me my data to a particular IP address.

I can't figure out what all the numbers mean. I got latitude and long thanks to the N and E. but the rest I'm not sure about.

Here's an extract from my log:

```
4/28/2011 6:48:01 PM (001__450BP00BP05000001__450BP00110428A2451.6491N06700.6385E000.013474342.72000000000L0001ADFE)    
4/28/2011 6:48:18 PM (001__450BP00BP05000001__450BP00110428A2451.6491N06700.6385E000.013480942.72000000000L0001ADFE)    
4/28/2011 6:49:23 PM (001__450BP00BP05000001__450BP00110428A2451.6491N06700.6385E000.013490942.72000000000L0001ADFE)    
4/28/2011 6:50:33 PM (001__450BP00BP05000001__450BP00110428A2451.6362N06700.6297E000.0135016198.8300000000L0001ADFE)    
4/28/2011 6:51:39 PM (001__450BP00BP05000001__450BP00110428A2451.5203N06700.5738E000.0135114135.3800000000L0001AEFF)    
4/28/2011 6:51:42 PM (001__450BP00BR02110428V2451.4962N06700.5942E000.0135133143.7700000000L0001AF23)
```

Note: the exact string from the tracker is stored within the round brackets (...)
I gave the dates and times because they may help decode the data if the tracker reports UTC time or something. Didn't see anything matching the time signature though

Comment: Can you post name of device and name of its biggest chips?

Comment: @osgx well, currently i don't have the device. it's at my client's. its a charity project for a charity. lol. theyve got it in their ambulance. but last i saw it it was a black box exactly like the one at this link [GPS 518 pdf](http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aitcl.com%2Fmanage%2Fupload%2F20106711284514.pdf&ei=gl3FTYn9MoOAhQezk73kAw&usg=AFQjCNFpwpz6MjxDIt8OzAZHmTCPCDyzGA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you post some more information (any serial numbers or other text on the device).
However, the messages look like [GPS518](http://www.google.nl/search?q=GPS518).

I'm mostly guessing, but if I deconstruct the first line, I think this is the meaning:

***Request***

- **001** : ?
- **450** : deviceid
- **BP00** : handshake
- **BP05** : command
- **000001** : ?

***Response***

- **450** : device id
- **BP00** : command
- **110428** : date (format `yymmdd`)
- **A**
- **2451.6491N** : Latitude
- **06700.6385E** : Longitude
- **000.0** : Speed (format `nnn.n`)
- **134743** : Time (format `hhmmss`as UTC) <sub>You probably live in GMT-7</sub>
- **42.720** : Heading/Bearing (?)
- **00000000L** : Elevation
- **0001ADFE** : ?

There's a discussion here that might be of interest:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/opengts/forums/forum/579834/topic/3871481

After some googling, I found this. It seems to generate message in roughly the same format as the ones that you are receiving:
http://kmmk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kmmk/src/com/gps/testmock/CommAdapterYD518.java

Comment: thanks!! 001 is the device id that is user specified :)  and yup! gps 518 it is! you are a genius! thanks for both the links. its enough to get me started.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the GPS data and parse it.

Please check the following link for more information:
https://github.com/anupama513/Tk102-gps-data-parser-nodejs-server

This is node js server:

1. listens continuously to the gps data
2. parse the GPRMC data
3. can store the data into database
4. Can also post the data to another webserver/socket.

The parse logic might be slightly different. But, most of the data matches.